# Display 2-D GIS polygon in 3-D street-level view

Tags: image-processing, gis, gdal, google-street-view, omr

I would like to drape some 2-D GIS polygon into a ‘3-D’ street level?

As a a picture is worth a thousand words, please check this:
[image]

So I have the azimuth angle, the view angle and the position where the image was taken along with the field limit in 2D and I would like to have the field plotted on my street-level image (as on the top image).